# How to use Dynamic Route in Server Side component with Supabase in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js, supabase

```
export default async function Page({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  // const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const id = searchParams?.p ?? "aaa"; // default value is "1"
  console.log(id);

  const supabase = createClient();
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("book")
    .select()
    .eq("id","asjiofeowef");

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-black md:p-5 md:flex">
        <div className="aspect-w-16 aspect-h-9 w-full md:w-8/12">
          <Youtube />
        </div>
        <div className="w-full md:w-4/12 p-5">
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have this file under `app/books/page.tsx`. And I want to get the `id` of the book using the dynamic route not the params.

I've been reading about `getServerSideProps` and most information about this did not work for some reasons. Either I got `"getServerSideProps" is not supported in app/. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching` error or  `satisfies GetServerSideProps ·    ────┬──── ────────────────── ·        ╰── This is the expression part of an expression statement`

I even copied and pasted the example from Nextjs app and did not work.

My question is

- How can I pass down the id on url when using the server side rendering? (app/books/[id]/page.tsx <--- is this the right way?)
- How can I find 'id' value from the url and then use it? (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props this example did not really help)
- How can I use my Supabase db type on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example you can create the following route inside your folder structure: `/app/books/[id]/page.tsx`. Inside your page you can then access the property the following way:

```
interface Props {
  params: { id: string };
}

export default async function Page({ params }: Props): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const { id } = params;
  return <>ID: {id ?? "1"}</>;
}
```

Please note that you should do some research on your own before posting to stack overflow. A look at the app router documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) would've probably sufficed.

Comment: I know I should not just come here for a help. I read how to do it for like 1-2 days but with 'use client' or server side with 'app' or 'page' made it a bit funcky. All the things that id tried did not work. And thank you so much for ur answer. Appreciated!